# 100% height resizing issue on IE 11

Tags: css

In my theme, http://ghost-theme-stretch.dreamsonline.net/ the initial header and its inner div is given 100% height.

e.g. HTML structure

```
<header id="site-head">
     <div class="site-head-background"></div>
     some content...
</header>
```

The code used to stretch these 2 elements to 100% screen height is:

```
$('.home-template #site-head').css({'height':(($(window).height()-30))+'px'});
$('.home-template .site-head-background').css({'height':(($(window).height()-30))+'px'});
```

I have also used JQuery plugin Backstretch http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ to apply a background image to the `<div class="site-head-background"></div>`.

This works great in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 11, the image is not stretched completely

[image]

I tried lot of things but still lost on how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this without plugins/js is to use the `vh` unit. It is fully supported in ie 11 (see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)). For example:

```
header {
    height: 800px; //fallback
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('..') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```