# css problems in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a web application and it goes without saying that cross browser is very important to me. My application works great on all browsers BUT IE11.

The piece of css in question is very simple

```
html,body {
    height:95%;
}
```

This is not working in IE11 and the page height is bigger than 100% of the screen.

The application is huge so I will not post small pieces of code which would only confuse you guys.

My question is: Any obvious issues with IE11 Height ? or should I be looking elsewhere ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, pages have margin. This means that in the absence of any CSS at all, your content will not squish against the edges of the window.

You must override this with `margin:0` if you wish to have control over the exact height of your document.

Comment: Thanks man but it's not the margins. It was definitely the % and vh problem

Answer (score 0):

First, seperate your `body` from the comma. Then use `vh` like here:

```
html, body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948544/100-height-resizing-issue-on-ie-11)  might help

Comment: There is no difference between `html, body` & `html,body` accept beautification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there are no issues with IE11 (even if I hate it) Your Code Should be like the code below.

```
body{
       height: 95%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `height: 100vh;` to your css class.
It is fully supported in ie 11

Comment: It did work for ie11 then ruined safari, I ended up setting the height using javascript

Comment: which version of safari you are using? [check here](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

Comment: 5.1 :P i know i was surprised too. I know it's old but compatibility for my company is a big thing